# Treewidth of complete bipartite graph using chordal graph characterisation?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, chordal-graphs

Compute the treewidth of $K_{m,n}$ if we know that
$$tw(G)=\min \{\omega(H)-1 : G\subseteq H \ \wedge \ H \ \text{is chordal}\}$$

I know it should be $\min\{m,n\}$ but I do not know how to construct the chordal graph. I mean in $K_{m,n}$ I have $4-$ and $6-$cycles. I mean, by hand it would be a lot of computing. Is there a trick on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1\le m\le n$ and the bipartition of the graph $G=K_{m,n}$ consists of $m$ red vertices and $n$ blue vertices.

Let $H$ be the graph with added edges between all pairs of red vertices. The graph $H$ is chordal because it has the following perfect elimination scheme (see, for instance, p.99 in the slides of a lecture “[Colorings, Cliques and Independent Sets](http://www.electronics.lnu.edu.ua/fileadmin/konferences/kursmatem/lec08-colorings-cliques.pdf)” by Joachim Spoerhase and Alexander Wolff). First we remove all blue vertices in any order and next all red vertices in any order.  Since any maximal clique of $H$ consists of all red vertices and one blue vertex, $\omega(H)=m+1$.

On the other hand, let $H’$ be a chordal graph containing $G$. I claim that either a subgraph $K’_m$ of $G$ induced on all red vertices of $H’$ is complete, or a subgraph $K’_n$ of $G$ induced on all blue vertices of $H’$ is complete. Indeed, if this doesn’t hold then there exist two non-adjacent red vertices $v_1$ and  $v_2$ and two non-adjacent blue vertices $u_1$ and  $u_2$. But then $v_1-u_1-v_2-u_2-v_1$ is a chordless cycle of $H’$ of length $4$, a contradiction. If the graph $K’_m$ is complete then $H$ contains a graph $H$ from the previous paragraph. So  $\omega(H)\ge  \omega(H’)=m+1$. If  the graph $K’_n$ then we similarly show that $\omega(H)\ge  n+1$. Anyway, $\omega(H)\ge m+1$.

Comment: So we proved that if $H'$ is any chordal graph, it will also have the clique number $m+1$. I am asking because I want to understand the minimality in the characterization of treewidth.

Comment: @zermelovac If $H′$ is any chordal graph containing $G$ then $\omega(H')\ge m+1$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. Thanks a lot, I understood the idea and the perfect elimination sheme is a nice tool.